# How to get just a File Name from the full path?

Tags: c#, file, file-io, classpath, filenames

I can't believe I'm having to ask this, because there's simple questions & then there's ridiculous questions .. 
Anyway, I'm actually unable to find out the answer due to the obvious answer (not the one I'm looking for).

I have code like this :

```
 OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if(ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName;
            }
```

This works good, because then I have a method, that of course, opens my file (different form).
 However, to pass this to my other form's viewing method the path (ofd.FileName) must remain in full.

My question, or problem is : How to get just the file's actual name from the path? 
I have tried this : `textBox1.Text = ofd.FileName.LastIndexOf("\");` 
The above attempt flagged as an error within the compiler because a back-slash is classed as a newline.

So, how can I gain the file name from the path? for instance, lets say the file's name is : List1.text, I would want my 2nd forms textBox1.Text to be : List1.text , rather than the full path.

Thanks in advance ! !

Comment: `System.Io.Path.GetFileName(string);`

Comment: The dirtiest workaround is `textBox1.Text = odf.FileName.Substring(ofd.FileName.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Path.GetFileName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in [Path Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.Path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir\myfile.ext";
string path = @"C:\mydir\";
string result;

result = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    fileName, result);

result = Path.GetFileName(path);
Console.WriteLine("GetFileName('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    path, result);

// This code produces output similar to the following: 
// 
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\myfile.ext') returns 'myfile.ext' 
// GetFileName('C:\mydir\') returns ''
```

if you want to get extension you can use [Path.GetExtension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension.aspx):

```
string fileName = @"C:\mydir.old\myfile.ext";
string path = @"C:\mydir.old\";
string extension;

extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
Console.WriteLine("GetExtension('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    fileName, extension);

extension = Path.GetExtension(path);
Console.WriteLine("GetExtension('{0}') returns '{1}'", 
    path, extension);

// This code produces output similar to the following: 
// 
// GetExtension('C:\mydir.old\myfile.ext') returns '.ext' 
// GetExtension('C:\mydir.old\') returns ''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the OpenFileDialog.SafeFileName from .net 4.0 and higher or use:

```
var onlyFileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(ofd.FileName);
```

[path.getfilename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[openfiledialog.safefilename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.safefilename.aspx)

Comment: Very easy solution, as expected. Thanks !